# Loop over data table columns and apply glm

Tags: r, for-loop, datatable

I am trying to loop over my data table columns and apply `glm` to each column using a for-loop. I then want to extract regression coefficients from the model and add them to my output data table.

Here `dt` is a data table and `y` is a vector:

```
output = data.table('reg_coef' = numeric())
for(n in 1:ncol(dt)){
  model = glm(y ~ dt[, n], family=binomial(link="logit"))
  reg_coef = summary(model)$coefficients[2]
  output = rbindlist(list(output, list(reg_coef)))
}
```

Why doesn't this work? I am getting this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , n) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'n' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..n]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the model and extract the coefficients in the same loop. Using `lapply` :

```
output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(names(dt), function(x) {
  model <- glm(reformulate(x, 'y'), dt, family=binomial(link="logit"))
  summary(model)$coefficients[2]
}))
```

Comment: What if I had to extract multiple coefficients?

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, is rbind or rbindlist better? I saw a post saying that rbind has worse performance.

Comment: How many columns do you have in your data?

Comment: @Ronak_Shah ~100

Answer (score 0):

We can use `paste`

```
output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(names(dt), function(x) {
 model <- glm(as.formula(paste0('y ~ ', x)), dt, family=binomial(link="logit"))
  summary(model)$coefficients[2]
   }))
```